# Job killed in terminal

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have this code which is supposed to record the RGB values of a pixel in several consecutive frames:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

N = 50000
data_rgb = []
for i in range(0,N):
    im = cv2.imread("frame%s.jpg" %i)
    data_rgb = data_rgb + [im[225][1625]]

data_rgb = np.array(data_rgb)
np.savetxt("frame_data.txt", data_rgb)
```

but after a while I am getting a `killed: 9` error message and the code is stopped. If I reduce N to around 1000, the code works fine. I assume there is some memory problem (the images gets stored while in the for loop)? But I am not sure what to do. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: I am still getting that error. I am not sure if it is a memory issue. That was just my guess.

Comment: Yeah I see you keep resizing `data_rgb` over and over, that seems unnecessary, just as it seems unnecessary that you do everything in a standard array just to throw it away at the end to use a `numpy` array instead. Try to make everything in one go. `data_rgb = np.zeros(N, dtype=integer)` and then fill it with the data specifying `i` as index.

Comment: Maybe it fails at a large number because the corresponding file to some of those larger indexes don't exist or fails to load. Maybe you should check if the file exist and was loaded successfully before assuming it was loaded and the data is there.